# how to check if a column type is composite type or not in Postgersql

Tags: postgresql

I want to check if a column type is **composite type** or not when I use select into statement.

Sample code is below. A way of selecting composite type and non-composite type are different, so I want to check that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc (_var INOUT anyelement, _table_name VARCHAR) AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF /* composite type? */ THEN
            EXECUTE 'SELECT (value).* FROM ' || _table_name INTO _var;
        ELSE
            EXECUTE 'SELECT value FROM ' || _table_name INTO _var;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer below, is there a better answer?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sample_function (_var INOUT anyelement, _table_name VARCHAR) AS $$
    DECLARE
        _typtype VARCHAR(1);
    BEGIN
        SELECT typtype INTO  _typtype FROM pg_type where OID = pg_typeof(_var);
        IF _typtype = 'c' THEN
            EXECUTE 'SELECT (value).* FROM ' || _table_name INTO _var;
        ELSE
            EXECUTE 'SELECT value FROM ' || _table_name INTO _var;
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But selecting pg_type is a bit slow?

Comment: No, that is the perfect solution. Catalog tables are cached, so catalog queries are fast.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe !! I didn't know the cache system, which is a good learning for me.